# Help with multiple item compatibility

Tags: mountain-bike, wheels, repair, fork, replacement

I have a [2004 Jamis Dakar 3.0](https://www.bicyclebluebook.com/searchlistingdetail.aspx?id=92456)

My front wheel was stolen a few weeks ago and since I am not the best at bike mechanics I had a few questions.

Wheel:

When looking for wheel do I just need to look for 26" (or are there other attributes i need to look at to ensure compatibility)?

Wheels I'm looking at: [SRAM RISE 40 Wheels](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B008OEBLIY)

Tire:

One tire I have picked out has 26 x 2.3-Inch as its size, so similar to the above question how do I ensure this will all be compatible?

Tires I'm looking at: [Maxxis EXO Dual Compound Minion](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00EEEBKP2)

Brakes:

Can I just expect that a 160m rotor will fit on the wheel and will also align with existing caliper?

Brake rotor I'm looking at: [160mm Rotor](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B06XH9DZ3B)

Front Suspension:

My front suspension is in need of replacing or an overhaul. Since the kit is $25 and the labor to get it done will probably be costly, I was wondering (once again similar to above) how would I find a replacement that would be compatible with my bike?

Front suspension I'm looking at: [SR SUNTOUR Mountain Bike Disc Fork](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00K2PFMI8)

Comment: That fork is junk compared to what is already on there. You'd probably be better off spending the money on overhauling the existing fork if you're doing any mountain biking.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I did some quick googling to double check you have a QR fork, which it appears you do. Thru-axles on trail bikes were uncommon then but not nonexistent. You should double check.

Wheel: You need any 26"/559 MTB disc wheel with a QR axle, which is a broad category. Even one from a different genre such as dirtjump/DH wheel would be physically compatible with the bike. You're looking at the right sort of thing. The main ways of messing up here would be getting something that's either thru axle, not a disc hub, or accidentally getting a 29" or 27.5" wheel.

Tire: Short answer is anything that says 26x2.3 (or narrower, ie 26x2.25) should be fine. The limit for that fork is nominally 2.4. Because tires are one of the areas where manufacturers can and do label things as smaller or larger than they actually are, there unfortunately is no magical way of knowing ahead of time beyond the shadow of a doubt that a given thing is going to fit, but that would more be something that could bite you if you were trying to run a 2.4.

Rotor:

If it says 160 and it's the right mounting (6-bolt versus centerlock) for your wheel it should be compatible. You should not expect it to work without having to adjust your brake, including resetting the pistons (fancy talk for inserting a thin degreased metal object between the pads and shoving them back into the caliper).

Fork:

$25US gets you the wiper seal kit for your fork, which is the basic seal kit that gets changed out as part of regular maintenance along with changing the oil. That's very different from overhaul. Overhaul means rebuilding the damper, replace bushings if needed, rebuild TALAS system, etc. If the fork is basically in good shape but just needs wipers and oil, that's very much worth it. If it's a heavily used 13 year old fork then yes, overhaul or replacement might make more sense. Note that if you're choosing between you personally sending the fork to Fox for $175 for overhaul but doing the removal and re-install yourself and getting a shop to install a whole new cheap fork, than the labor involved with the latter plus the cost of the fork itself can easily have you paying a ballpark similar amount for much less performance/quality, presuming a situation where the Fox was a good candidate for overhaul in the first place, i.e. no damage to stanchions or elsewhere. If you want to replace it, all you're really looking for is another 26" QR disc-compatible fork with 100-120mm of travel and the desired amount of tire clearance. Most forks today are now post mount for the brake, which just means you won't be using your brake adapter presuming you have the Juicy 7s that are listed as coming with the bike.